# How do I use Admob Live ads on my app?

Tags: java, android, admob

I have an app ready to be published on store on which I've used Banner Ads from Admob and I've been using a Test ID as of late. I have my Admob ID with me, but can I update the test ID with the real ID and run it on the emulator once for updating the code? As far as I know the changes aren't reflected back in the .apk file until the project isn't run again on the emulator.

I fear since this is a live ad, I cannot use it for development purpose. Also, what changes would I need to make in an order to get the app working with live ads? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: your question is not quite clear. Can you be specific as to what you exactly want to do?

Comment: I am using Banner ads in my app currently on test ID. I want to export the apk to production. What changes do I need to make? Do I need to run the project once after updating the Admob ID to ensure things are running fine? .apk also gets updated every time app runs on the emulator so apk will get updated with live ads?

Comment: no you dont need to do anything in that case.  always keep emulator there  in test devices so that you never get any live ads on it. Adding more info to my answer check in a minute.

Answer (score 6):

If you added a device id as test device, only that device will get test ads. When you generate a signed apk and upload it to production all other device will get live ads. Your device will continue to get test ads since the test device id is hard coded. If you want to receive live ads on your device too after publishing it. Remove the test device id before generating the signed apk for publishing.

If your apps is already working with ads and you are just changing the `ad unit id`, there is no need to test as long as you are correctly replacing the ad unit it string.

Following is how you should ad `test device ids`:

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
    .addTestDevice("AC98C820A50B4AD8A2106EDE96FB87D4")  // An example device ID
    .build();
```

Do not remove `DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR` and you'll never get live ads on your emulator.

The second id is your test device id, remove it only if you want to start getting live ads on the device. I would suggest leave it to avoid the complication of accidentally clicking ads on your own app and getting banned by google.

Comment: There are two ways to get test ads. One using addTestDevice and give the device id as mentioned by you and Second to use test Admob id given at https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=en . This admob id must be replaced by your admob id to get live ads. I think the asker is using second method

Comment: added an explanation for that too in the answer. thanks

Comment: I think he is talking about this     <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string> test id and not about test device id

Comment: yes check the second paragraph, thats what i've mentioned

Comment: @ Virus, all I need to do is update the test id with my admob id? After this step, file -> export? Yes, by test id, I mean -> 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111'

Comment: no no no ... :-) dont complicate it. First, just forget about test device ids. Leave them as they are. It is good to keep them if there are already there. Test device id and Ad unit id are different things. You cannot replace one with another. Test device id is the id of device where you want to get test ads. Ad unit id is what admob provides you and you use it to make ad requests to get ads on your app. Dont mix the two up.

Comment: Yes, that's what my question is. All I need to do is replace the dummy ad unit id with real ad unit id and then go to file -> export?

Comment: Ad unit id is what @AkshitRewari has shown in his answer in the code snippet. Test device ids are what you see in my answer's code snippet. Both are totally different things.

Comment: where is your dummy ad unit id right now? It will either be in strings.xml like shown by akshit, or in your java code in the AdRequest, or your layout xml if you created the adview in xml. Just replace the id there and you should be good.

Comment: share your layout xml and java code specific to admob  in your question. Let me take a look and I'll tell you.

Comment: It's there in the strings.xml.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**No. You must not use live ads even once during development, Your account will be suspended.**

Update your Admob ID and see advertising data in your dashboard after publishing the update. Never use live ads

Go to strings.xml and find this line

```
 <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
```

and replace the contents of `<string>` tag with your admob id and publish. But do not view live ads. To test your admob ID use addTestDevice as mentioned by @Virus

Comment: I just need to update the Admob ID before exporting the apk? No need to test it even once to ensure things are up and running?

Comment: @HarshwardhanS there should be no reason to change your ids. See Virus's answer for more details.

Comment: @CoryCharlton There are two ways to get test ads. One using addTestDevice and give the device id as mentioned by virus and Second to use test Admob id given at developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=en . This admob id must be replaced by your admob id to get live ads. Which one r u using?

Comment: @AkshitRewari interesting, I was not aware of the test Ad Unit ID as I always use my application specific ID and do the add test device.

Comment: @CoryCharlton Even I wasn't aware of it few minutes ago :) . Just read the updated google documentation

Comment: @ Cory Charlton You just solved my question. I was unsure about what changes to make after changing test ad unit id to application specific id.

Comment: @AkshitRewari How can I make sure that when I use the live ads, there won't be any problem after obfuscation?